# Webpack does not find my css file

Tags: css, import, webpack

I'm strugling to import a css file with webpack. I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../style/style.css in c:\developement\prja/app
 @ ./index.js 11:0-29
```

I tried all sorts of path for the style.css. like `'css!../style/style.css'`, `'/style/style.css'` or `'./style/style.css'` but none of them works. I also tried to use require instead of import. But I keep getting the same error message.

Any ideas?

My index.js entry point file looks like this:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery';
import angular from 'angular';
import 'bootstrap-webpack';
import '../style/style.css';

var ngModule = angular.module('app', []);
```

An this is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    }

};
```

And this is my file sctructure:

```
|   lighthouse.iml
|   package.json
|   webpack.config.js
|   
+---app
|       index.html
|       index.js      
|               
\---style
        style.css
```

Comment: because of your `context: __dirname + '/app'`. In this case webpack always starts looking into your `/app` folder. Solution move your style folder into app or remove `/app` from the context property

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Feel free to add this as answer in order I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem related to `context` property and you file structure.

`context` - The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the entry option, [`webpack docs`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html). In other words, this is the folder where `webpack` starts looking into your app. Here is two way how to fix it:

1. Remove `/app` from `context` property ->  `context: __dirname` or you can even remove `context` from your *weblack.config* file
2. Move your *style* folder into *app* folder

Thanks!